# Как ослуществляется выборка данный в модульной или микросервисной архитектуре?

Tags: ооп, архитектура, шаблоны-проектирования, микросервисы, модульность

Всем привет. Озадачился вопросом реализации модульного монолита и возник следующий вопрос:

Допустим у нас есть некоторое e-commerce система. Она имеет несколько модулей, к примеру модуль магазина, который содержит данные о заказах и товарах, и модуль платежей. Далее перед нами стоит задача вывести заказы 30 заказов на странице, которые имеет статус X, и которые оплачены платёжной системой Y при условии, что заказов и платежей может быть очень большое число.

Если у нас монолит, то данная задача решается простейшим SQL запросом с лимитом, однако если у нас есть модульность, то вот тут у меня и возникает вопрос. Т.к. мы не можем сделать выборку всех заказов в статусе X, т.к. их очень много, но мы и не можем сделать выборку с лимитом т.к. не знаем точно, что данные заказы будут оплачены платёжной системой Y и наоборот, если будем строить выборку от оплат. В общем получается, что мы решаем вопросы, которые легко решены в БД, но мы их пытаемся решить в коде. Как поступать то?

Comment: Не совсем ясна проблема. Что мешает сделать выборку в модуле платёжной системы? Есть сущность, за которую произошла оплата, она может спокойно находиться в модуле........Как минимум в простейшем виде храня её идентификатор..............а в системе заказов сделать запрос по API к платёжной системе и получив данные через адаптер (или через corruption layer) отдать полученные данные в запрос по заказу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Интересная мысль, спасибо вам. Но если мы усложним задачу, к примеру один заказ может иметь сразу несколько оплат. В таком случае мы можем иметь доп. таблицу в модуле заказов, которая будет связывать эту историю (order_id, payment_id), да это является хороший оптимизацией запросов, но ведь это создаст дополнительную связанность, наш модуль узнал о том, что существуют некоторые идентификаторы оплат. Мы добавили отвественность нашему модулю. И ещё вопрос, а что если стоит задача о создании некоторого отчета, который должен ходить в разные модули и собирать данные?

Comment: вот тут как проблема в логике `если у нас есть модульность, то ... мы не можем сделать выборку всех заказов в статусе X`. Не важно, монолит у вас или не монолит, за заказы всегда должно отвечать единое место, откуда легко сделать выборку. Если для того, чтобы получить выборку заказов, вам надо делать сальто через несколько сервисов, то, скорее всего, сервисы разделены не оч удачно.

Comment: *"мы можем иметь доп. таблицу в модуле заказов, которая будет связывать"*  --- я такого не писал..... Я писал о том, что в модуле оплаты может быть в таблице идентификатор сущности..... в рамках "связанного контекста" (если рассматривать DDD) это вполне легально.......... А потом из модуля заказов идёт API по order_id к модулю оплат, получая данные......потом их применяя дл выборки в модуле и заказов...так что никаких мы там отвественностей и лишнего не добавляли.........и никакой связанности нет. а обращение через endpoint - вряд ли можно рассматривать как серьёзную связанность...........

Comment: *"задача о создании некоторого отчета, который должен ходить в разные модули"* -- если это модульный монолит и БД одна на всё - то никто в какие модули может даже не ходить. Отчёт - это своего рода "контекст". Если брать DDD то в связанных контекстах могут "повторяться" сущности. И в модуле отчёта допустимо иметь сущности заказ, покупатель, оплата и вообще одной выборкой залезть в БД.С микросервисами уже сложнее. В связи с распределённостью - придётся танцевать со сбором инфы..Хотя, честно говоря, не вижу проблемы иметь подписчика в микросервисе отчётов и заполнять таблицу данными по событиям.

Comment: А потом всё так же одним запросом эту таблицу/таблицы кушать и наполнять сущности **конкретно этого связанного контекста**

Comment: @АлексейШиманский благодарю вас за развернутые комментарии. Отчасти я вас понимаю, но некоторые моменты мне ещё не ясны, вот смотрите. У нас некий фронт, который хочет вывести отчет по заказам, он знает о 2-х end-point'ах, получить список заказов с фильтром по полям заказа и такой же эндпоинт, но в оплаты с соответствующим фильтром, оплаты содержат идентификатор заказа. У заказа может быть несколько оплат, наша задача получить данные по заказам в статусе X с оплатами из платёжной системы Y. Какие есть варианты решений?

Comment: @tym32167 это гипотетический пример. Мы можем предположить, что у нас на этапе разработки такого требования не стояло. Да, конечно, мы как разработчики допустили ошибку, что не продумали этот момент, но что теперь делать с задачей, которую я описал в комментарии выше.

Comment: @skDYLAN *"некий фронт знает о 2-х end-point'ах....."* --- на фронт надо вообще наплевать. И то, что он знает два каких-то там эндпойнта - тоже. Отчёт - это новый контекст. Читай как "новый модуль". Это совсем другая сущность. Поэтому фронт **должен** посылать запрос на 3-ий эндпойнт `/report/payed-orders` или как-то так.... И на сервере новый модуль отчётов, по присланным данным уже формирует всё что нужно.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо, стало чуть понятнее. Если у нас появилось требование сложного отчета, то это будет отдельный модуль, реализацию у него может быть разной. Он может подписаться на изменения в системе, слушать события и организовывать хранение данных таким образом, чтобы ему было удобно их извлекать. Но получается, что теперь мы создали проблему избыточности данных. Информация о заказах и оплатах будет находится в нескольких местах системы. Но если это модульный монолит, наш модуль может ходить в общую базу, но тогда появляется дополнительная ответственность.

Comment: *"Информация о заказах и оплатах будет находится в нескольких местах системы."* --- какая информация? И где? В БД или в виде сущностей в коде? Ничего такого не будет......Думаю, стОит почитать и посмотеть видео на тему DDD. Это должно помочь, т.к. это направление похожее к миросервисам... Слишком обширный вопрос, который требует обсуждения, получается.......Ещё советую посмотреть видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xT25xiKqPcI  о модульном монолите. Там примерно то, о чём я говорю, есть. И о взаимодействии между модулями без сильной связанности тоже.....Это шаг в сторону DDD и микросервисов.

Comment: Спасибо больше за информацию и потраченное вами время, если есть какие-то ещё ссылки или книги (можно на английском), то буду признателен! ))) Можете просто резюмировать ваш ответ в ответе, чтобы я мог его пометить как решение к данному вопросу, чтобы хоть таким способом отблагодарить за ваш труд.